# Open balls with center $\pm\infty$ in the extended real line

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, real-numbers

Define a function $f$ from $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ to the interval $[-1,1]$ as follows: For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, let $f(x)=x/(1+|x|)$; on the other hand, write $f(\infty)=1$ and $f(-\infty)=-1$. Then $d(x,y):=|f(x)-f(y)|$ defines a metric on the real extended line $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

What do the open balls of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ centred at $\infty$ look like? Take $0<r$. Then
$$B(\infty;r)=\left\{x\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}\ :\ 1-r<\frac{x}{1+|x|}<1+r\right\}.$$
Can $B(\infty;r)$ be written in the form of an interval?

Comment: Are you sure about the definition of $f$ (or of $d$)? Since $f$ is not injective, $d$ is not a distance.

Comment: You're right, there's a big typo! I will fix it now.

Comment: $\infty$ is an endpoint, so the interval is $$\left\{x\in\overline{\Bbb R}:1-r<\frac{x}{1+|x|}\le 1\right\}\,.$$ (And of course you want $r\le 2$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:\begin{align}B(\infty;r)&=\left\{x\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}\,\middle|\,1-r<\frac{x}{1+|x|}<1+r\right\}\\&=\left\{x\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}\,\middle|\,1-r<\frac{x}{1+|x|}\leqslant1\right\}\\&=\left(f^{-1}(1-r),\infty\right]\end{align}if $r<2$. Besides, $B(\infty,2)=(-\infty,\infty]$ and, if $r>2$, $B(\infty,r)=\overline{\Bbb R}$.

Comment: Thank you. Is $f^{-1}(r)=r/(1-|r|)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Pardon me; would you please help me see why $r/(1-r)<x\leq\infty$ is equivalent to $1-r<\frac{x}{1+|x|}\leq 1$ (when $0<r<2$)?

Comment: I did not claim that. What I wrote was that$$1-r<\frac 1{1+|x|}\leqslant1\iff f^{-1}(1-r)<x\leqslant\infty.$$

Comment: Sorry my bad. I meant to write $$1-r<\frac{1}{1+|x|}\leq 1\iff \frac{1-r}{1-|r-1|}<x\leq\infty.$$ I am not able to prove this. Should I break it down to cases $0\leq x$ and $x\leq 0$?

Comment: No. Just is the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing and that it maps $\infty$ into $1$. So,\begin{align}f^{-1}(1-r)<x\leqslant\infty&\iff f\bigl(f^{-1}(1-r)\bigr)<f(x)\leqslant f(\infty)\\&\iff1-r<\frac1{1+|x|}\leqslant1.\end{align}